# creating RadioButton with no results

Tags: java, android

i have created buttons succesfully but now i want each button to have a radiobutton beneath it i did what im supposed to do but still not working the error is saying no resource identifier for found for attribute weight and this error is showing on the three radio buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Greetings"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.3"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/red"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.4"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/green"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.3"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/blue"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonRed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonGreen"
        style="@style/styleName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonBlue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weight="1" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: i want the radiobuttons to be beneath the textview (red,blue,green)

Comment: Why dont you just assign values to the RadioButtons instead of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your radio group by this

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
          >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonRed"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonGreen"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonBlue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have some mess with weight, layout_weight, and weightSum. 
This fixed code should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android2="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Greetings"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/red"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/green"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000ff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/blue"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/myRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:weightSum="3">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonRed"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonGreen"
            style="@style/styleName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/myRadioButtonBlue"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```